# Circuit simplification to find Thévenin resistance

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, impedance, thevenin

I've been trying to work out an equivalent resistance using Thévenin, but I'm not 100% sure if what I've done is correct or if I'm missing steps. I've attached my "working out" (this isn't a homework question, I'm just an enthusiast trying to learn more).

Can someone tell me if this is correct or if I'm missing something? The load is the input of the op-amp which I've set as 100 MΩ.

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 4 is incorrect. The 200 ohm resistor is shorted and the 12kohm resistor is in parallel with the 1Mohm one (assuming you're trying to calculate the thèvenin impedance across the 1Mohm terminals).

Finally, the 100Mohm resistor (I guess the op-amp input impedance) seems to be the load in your schematic. If so, you're calculating the equivalent impedance of your preceding circuit so that you can model it as a thèvenin voltage source in series with this impedance you're calculating. The 100Mohm will be the load.

Your result should be approx. a 12kohm thèvenin impedance.

The thèvenin equivalent voltage should be:

$$
V_{th} = V_{in}\frac{1M\Omega}{1M\Omega + 12k\Omega}
$$

Once you have voltage source and series impedance, you can then calculate what the voltage at the input of the op-amp will be. You'll see that it'll be your input voltage \$V_{in}\$ multiplied by a factor very close to 1.

Comment: Thank you! I know I was getting close-ish, but just needed direction. out of curiosity why is the 200ohm resistor shorted? Apology for the stupid question in advance :)

Comment: @DylanBenton (1/2) in step 2 you correctly recognize that a voltage source, when turned off, is a short (while a current source will be an open). As such, you can see there's now a wire in parallel with the 200ohm resistor, which is shorting it (what's 0ohm||200ohm? zero ohms). You can understand this, conceptually, by recognizing that an ideal voltage source can provide infinite current.

Comment: @DylanBenton (2/2) Therefore, it doesn't matter that resistance you put there to ground, the ideal voltage source will always be able to provide the correct current to get that node to the voltage provided by your ideal voltage source.

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic explanation! thats helped me to no end :)

Comment: Done ☺️ will go over it today and let it soak in ☺️